# Как изменить свойство виджета в GTK?

Tags: c++, c, gui, gtk

У всех виджетов в GTK есть свойства (properties), для изменения состояния некоторых из них есть встроенные функции, например У `GtkColorButton` есть свойство `title` и есть соответствующие функции `gtk_color_button_set_title` & `gtk_color_button_get_title`. Но есть у `GtkColorButton` свойство `show-editor` и встроенной функции для доступа к нему нет, вопрос: как изменить значение этого поля?
Я пробовал использовать `gtk_container_child_set` и `gtk_container_set_property` - не помогло, выдаётся ошибка что нет такого свойства. В некоторых ответах на SO упоминалась функция `gtk_widget_set_property`, но в официальной документации она не фигурирует, если попытаться напрямую изменить поле: `button->show_editor`, то тоже ничего не получается. Можно ли вообще изменить это свойство?

Comment: Приведите код как вы устанавливаете свойства, и еще укажите верcию Gtk.

Comment: Я пробовал устанавливать свойства следующим кодом: `gtk_container_child_set(GTK_CONTAINER(gtk_widget_get_parent(ch_color_bttn)), ch_color_bttn, "show-editor", FALSE, NULL);`, где `ch_color_bttn` - кнопка типа `GtkColorButton`.
Версия GTK+ 3.24.24-1

Answer (score 0):

Свойства можно установить через функции `g_object_set_*`

```
GtkColorButton * button = gtk_color_button_new();
gboolean show_editor_flag = TRUE;
g_object_set(G_OBJECT(button), "show-editor", &show_editor_flag, NULL);
```

Так же свойства можно устанавливать через файлы настройки *.css. Theming GTK